# How to add a web page to an existing one? (HTML5)

Tags: css, html

I'm new to coding in HTML5 and I'm building my first website. How would I, for example, link an Events page to a About Us page?
So in this order: Home Page>About Us>Events.
I feel like I'm probably over thinking it but I can't find an answer anywhere. I need the two pages linked. Would I just add another navigation option to the About Us page?

Comment: Hi Sparx - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below an answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. ***Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question.*** If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a static HTML site, you could just set up your folder structure like:

```
/home
    - index.html
    - /about
        - index.html
        - /events
            - index.html
```

Then each index page would be linked to any of the others like

```
<a href="./about">About Us</a>
```

Then just do whatever in the bodies of the pages.

Lots of other ways to do this if you have a backend or frontend framework.

Answer (score 0):

Each page is a separate `.html` file.

At the top of each html file, you have a navbar. This can be constructed of `<li></li>` elements displayed inline, or it can be a series of `<div>`s (again, with the inner divs styled inline or inline-block), or it can be a table (bad idea, but just saying...).

Each "cell" of your navbar contains an `<a href="">` link, that links off to the other pages. For example, with the common `<li>` format:

```
<ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" class="active">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="summat.html">Summat Else</a></li>
</ul>
```

On the about page, you would give the link for that page a special className ("active" is popular), and you use CSS to style that link to appear active - perhaps a slightly darker background and yellow text, or some such.

```
.active{color:yellow;background:darkcyan;}
```

On each page, you assign the link *for that page* to have the active class. That way, on each page the nav link for that page shows the user that that is the page they are on.

If the user is on the home (index.html) page and clicks, say, the about page - the `<a>` tag on which they click will send them over to the `about.html` page. It is that simple. If all the pages are in the same directory on your server (or in xampp), then there is no need for any preceeding slashes or anything like that.

On the about page, you can have another addition to your menu for the Events page - and just do exactly the same thing you did before, but now you add an `<li>` for the events.html page. *It is common for the navbar to appear* ***similar*** *on each page, but not identical -- usually, each page has one or more navbar links that are unique to that page.*

Answer (score 0):

The **href** attribute specifies the link's destination:

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>
```

Syntax:

```
<a href="URL">
```

You can use the **href** attribute in order to directly redirect to another page of your website:

```
<a href="./contact">Contact page</a> 
<a href="./home">Home page</a>
```